# I want to store Javascript array as a Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Is it possible, I have a some sort of list and I want to store it on browser, if it is not possible, what is the efficient way of doing this?

Comment: see this example I created  [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470477/create-array-in-cookie-with-javascript/62686800#62686800)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

JSON encode it, effectively producing a string like `"{name:'myname',age:'myage'}"` which you put in a cookie, retrieve when needed and decode back into a JavaScript array/object.

Example - store array in a cookie:

```
var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
var json_str = JSON.stringify(arr);
createCookie('mycookie', json_str);
```

Later on, to retrieve the cookie's contents as an array:

```
var json_str = getCookie('mycookie');
var arr = JSON.parse(json_str);
```

**Note:** cookie functions are not native, taken from [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Answer (score 35):

One quick method is to [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) your array into a single string, using an appropriate delimiter:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
a.join('|');  // Returns: "1|2|3|4"
```

Then simply use the string [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to get the array back from the cookie string.

Comment: A minor correction, it needs to be assigned as new variable like this, `var new_a = a.join('|')` which will return "1|2|3|4".

Answer (score 3):

For each value id in an array, please try below method to save a value in a cookie array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/**
 * set cookie
 */
function set_cookie(cookiename, cookievalue, hours) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + Number(hours) * 3600 * 1000);
    document.cookie = cookiename + "=" + cookievalue + "; path=/;expires = " + date.toGMTString();

}

set_cookie('item['+id+']', id, 24*365*10); // 10 years

</script>
```

And you can retrieve this array in php:

```
<?php
foreach($_COOKIE['item'] as $e){
echo $e,'<br />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume cart is array we can set it with

```
document.cookie = 'cart='+ JSON.stringify(cart)
```

Then, you have to create a function to read cookie

```
function getCookie(cookieName) {
    var name = cookieName + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if ((c.indexOf(name)) == 0) {
            return c.substr(name.length);
        }
    }
}
```

then you can get cookie with

```
cart = JSON.parse(getCookie('cart'))
```