# Create array in cookie with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is it possible to create a cookie using arrays?

I would like to store `a[0]='peter'`, `a['1']='esther'`, `a['2']='john'` in a cookie in JavaScript.

Comment: Given the nature of arrays, a cooke (limited size) is the last place I would attempt to store one / the last storage method I'd attempt to use.

Answer (score 63):

As you can read in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163815/cookie-array-in-javascript):

You combine the use [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin and [JSON](http://www.json.org/) and solve your problem.

When you want to store an array, you create an array in JS and use `JSON.stringify` to transform it into an string and stored with `$.cookie('name', 'array_string')`

```
var myAry = [1, 2, 3];
$.cookie('name', JSON.stringify(myAry));
```

When you want to retrive the array inside the cookie, you use `$.cookie('name')` to retrive the cookie value and use `JSON.parse` to retrive the array from the string.

```
var storedAry = JSON.parse($.cookie('name'));
//storedAry -> [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 10):

Cookies can hold only strings. If you want to simulate an array you need to serialize it and deserialize it.

You could do this with a [JSON](http://json.org/) library.

Comment: I just need to store an array of string. Is it possible with simpler method?

Comment: This is a simple method. There are simpler methods, but they are only slightly simpler and quite a lot less robust.

Comment: Definitely use JSON. You could store "['foo','bar']" and eval it later but it can be a disaster in terms of performance and stability.

Comment: this is the first time i encounter json with cookie. Can you give me an example? Coz normally I link json with ajax. Thanks..

Comment: JSON is just a string which can be turned into a JavaScript object. You just store the string in a cookie instead of posting it with or reading it from an XMLHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 3):

I add the code below ***Script*** (see the following code) into a javascript file called `CookieMonster.js`.

It's a wrapper around the current snippet from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

It works with arrays and strings, it will automagically escape your array/string's commas `,` and semi-colons `;` (which are not handled in the original snippets).

**I have listed the simple usage and some bonus usage I built into it.**

Usage:

```
//set cookie with array, expires in 30 days
var newarray = ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's6', 's7'];
cookiemonster.set('series', newarray, 30); 

var seriesarray = cookiemonster.get('series'); //returns array with the above numbers

//set cookie with string, expires in 30 days
cookiemonster.set('sample', 'sample, string;.', 30); 

var messagestring = cookiemonster.get('sample'); //returns string with 'sample, string;.'
```

Bonuses:

```
//It also conveniently contains splice and append (works for string or array (single string add only)).

//append string
cookiemonster.append('sample', ' add this', 30); //sample cookie now reads 'sample, string;. add this' 

//append array
cookiemonster.append('series', 's8', 30); //returns array with values ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's6', 's7', 's8'] 

//splice
cookiemonster.splice('series', 1, 2, 30); //returns array with values ['s1', 's4', 's5', 's6', 's7', 's8']
```

CookieMonster.js :

```
        var cookiemonster = new Object();

        cookiemonster.append = function (cookieName, item, expDays) {
            item = cm_clean(item);
            var cookievalue = cookiemonster.get(cookieName);
            if (cookievalue instanceof Array) {
                cookievalue[cookievalue.length] = item;
                cm_createCookie(cookieName, cm_arrayAsString(cookievalue), expDays);
            } else {
                cm_createCookie(cookieName, cookievalue + item, expDays);
            }
        };

        cookiemonster.splice = function (cookieName, index, numberToRemove, expDays) {
            var cookievalue = cookiemonster.get(cookieName);
            if (cookievalue instanceof Array) {
                cookievalue.splice(index, numberToRemove);
                cm_createCookie(cookieName, cm_arrayAsString(cookievalue), expDays);
            }
        };



        cookiemonster.get = function (cookieName) {
            var cstring = cm_readCookie(cookieName);
            if (cstring.indexOf('<#&type=ArrayVals>') != -1) {

                var carray = cstring.split(',');

                for (var i = 0; i < carray.length; i++) {
                        carray[i] = cm_dirty(carray[i]);
                }

                if (carray[0] == '<#&type=ArrayVals>') {
                    carray.splice(0, 1);
                }

                return carray;

            } else {

                return cm_dirty(cstring);
            }
        };

        cookiemonster.set = function (cookieName, value, expDays) {
            if (value instanceof Array) {
                cm_createCookie(cookieName, cm_arrayAsString(value), expDays);
            }
            else { cm_createCookie(cookieName, cm_clean(value), expDays); }

        };

        cookiemonster.eraseCookie = function (name) {
            cm_createCookie(name, "", -1);
        };

        function cm_replaceAll(str, find, replace) {

            return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
        };

        function cm_clean(ret) {
            ret = cm_replaceAll(ret.toString(), ',', '&#44');
            ret = cm_replaceAll(ret.toString(), ';', '&#59');
            return ret;
        };
        function cm_dirty(ret) {
            ret = cm_replaceAll(ret, '&#44', ',');
            ret = cm_replaceAll(ret, '&#59', ';');
            return ret;
        };

        function cm_createCookie(name, value, days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            } else var expires = "";
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
        };

        function cm_readCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        };

        function cm_arrayAsString(array) {
            var ret = "<#&type=ArrayVals>"; //escapes, tells that string is array
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    ret = ret + "," + cm_clean(array[i]);
            }
            return ret;
        };
```

Comment: Great for unidimensional arrays, not for multidimensional ones!

Comment: Absolutely a limitation of that snippet. It should take care of the majority of use cases though.

Answer (score 1):

Create array in cookie using jQUery?

```
var list = new cookieList("test"); $(img).one('click', function(i){ while($('.selected').length < 3) {
    $(this).parent()
        .addClass("selected")
        .append(setup.config.overlay);

    //$.cookie(setup.config.COOKIE_NAME, d, setup.config.OPTS);
    var index = $(this).parent().index();

    // suppose this array go into cookies.. but failed
    list.add( index );

    var count = 'You have selected : <span>' + $('.selected').length + '</span> deals';
    if( $('.total').length ){
        $('.total').html(count);
    }

}  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with other comments - you should not be doing this and you should be using JSON. However, to answer your question you could hack this by storing the array as a comma-delimited string. Lets say you wanted to save a the following Javascript array into a cookie:

```js
var a = ['peter','esther','john'];
```

You could define a cookie string, then iterate over the array:

```js
// Create a timestamp in the future for the cookie so it is valid
var nowPreserve = new Date();
var oneYear = 365*24*60*60*1000; // one year in milliseconds
var thenPreserve = nowPreserve.getTime() + oneYear;
nowPreserve.setTime(thenPreserve);
var expireTime = nowPreserve.toUTCString();

// Define the cookie id and default string
var cookieId = 'arrayCookie';
var cookieStr = '';

// Loop over the array
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    cookieStr += a[i]+',';
}

// Remove the last comma from the final string
cookieStr = cookieStr.substr(0,cookieStr.length-1);

// Now add the cookie
document.cookie = cookieId+'='+cookieStr+';expires='+expireTime+';domain='+document.domain;
```

In this example, you would get the following cookie stored (if your domain is www.example.com):

```js
arrayCookie=peter,ester,john;expires=1365094617464;domain=www.example.com
```

Comment: I know this is old, but you could have just done var a = ['peter','esther','john'].join(); And then remove the loop and substr.

Answer (score 1):

I've created this easy way to get cookies. It'll give error if execute here, but it's functional

```js
var arrayOfCookies = [];
function parseCookieToArray()
{
    var cookies      = document.cookie;
    var arrayCookies = cookies.split(';');
    arrayCookies.map(function(originalValue){
        var name  = originalValue.split('=')[0];
        var value = originalValue.split('=')[1];
        arrayOfCookies[name] = value;
    });
}
console.log(arrayOfCookies); //in my case get out: [language: 'en_US', country: 'brazil']
parseCookieToArray();
```

**New**
My new obj to `create` `get` cookies

```
cookie = {
    set: function(name, value) {
        document.cookie = name+"="+value;
    },
    get: function(name) {
        cookies = document.cookie;
        r = cookies.split(';').reduce(function(acc, item){
            let c = item.split('='); //'nome=Marcelo' transform in Array[0] = 'nome', Array[1] = 'Marcelo'
            c[0] = c[0].replace(' ', ''); //remove white space from key cookie
            acc[c[0]] = c[1]; //acc == accumulator, he accomulates all data, on ends, return to r variable
            return acc; //here do not return to r variable, here return to accumulator
        },[]);
    }
};
cookie.set('nome', 'Marcelo');
cookie.get('nome');
```

Comment: Wouldn't this set the entire cookie and not just the individual value?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest form of adding a cookie in array format.

```
function add_to_cookie(variable, value) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); //equivalent to 1 month
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = "cookie_name[" + variable + "]" + "=" + value + ";" + expires + ';path=/';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that example you can do it quite easily:

- Make Cookies:

  ```
  ///W3Schools Cookie Code:
  function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
      var d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
      var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
      document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";";
  }

  function getCookie(cname) {
      var name = cname + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
              c = c.substring(1);
          }
          if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
              return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
          }
      }
      return "";
  }

  ///My Own Code:
  for(a=0;a<b.length;a++){
      setCookie(b[a],b[a],periodoftime);
  }
  ```
- Retrieve Array:

  ```
  for(a=0;a<b.length;a++){
      b[a] = getCookie(b[a])
  }
  ```

For any array with other value types besides strings:

- Make Cookies:

  ```
  ///Replace MyCode above With:
  if(typeof b[a] === 'string'){
      setCookie(b[a],b[a],periodoftime);
  }else{
      setCookie(b[a].toString,b[a],periodoftime);
  }
  ```
- Retrieve Array:

  ```
  for(a=0;a<b.length;a++){
      if(typeof b[a] === 'string'){
          b[a] = getCookie(b[a])
      }else{
          b[a] = getCookie(b[a].toString)
      }
  }
  ```

The only flaw is that identical values cannot be retrieved.

No JQuery needed, comma seperation or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Added remove to cookiemonster

```
// remove item

cookiemonster.remove('series', 's6', 30); //returns array with values ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's7', 's8'] 

    cookiemonster.remove = function (cookieName, item,  expDays) {
        var cookievalue = cookiemonster.get(cookieName);
        //Find the item
        for( var i = 0; i < cookievalue.length; i++) {
            if ( cookievalue[i] === item) { 
                cookievalue.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        cm_createCookie(cookieName, cm_arrayAsString(cookievalue), expDays);
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can save a lot of data within a single cookie and return it as an array, try this

```
  function setCookie(cookieKey, cookieValue) {
        var cookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)idpurchase\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1")
        var idPurchase = cookie.split(",")
        idPurchase.push(cookieValue)
        document.cookie = cookieKey+"=" + idPurchase
        console.log("Id das compras efetuadas :",idPurchase)
        $("#purchases_ids option:last").after($('<option onclick="document.getElementById("input_class1").value='+cookieValue+'" value="'+cookieValue+'">'+cookieValue+'</option>'))
    }
    checkCookie()
    function checkCookie() {
        var cookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)idpurchase\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1")
        var idPurchase = cookie.split(",")
        console.log("Id das compras efetuadas :",idPurchase)
        for (i = 1; i < idPurchase.length; i++) {
        $("#purchases_ids option:last").after($('<option value="'+idPurchase[i]+'">'+idPurchase[i]+'</option>'))
        }
        purchases_ids.addEventListener("change",changeSpeed)
    }
```

in this project that I created I store values ​​in arrays, codePen is not allowing the storage of cookies, but in the example below you can get a complete picture, just study the implementation

[Github project](https://github.com/Allanksr/appmeunegocio/blob/d73c096bccefc5b530dbc0d8e17d4e99b7db5e3e/Projeto-App-Meu-Negocio/Implementacao-Pagar-me/views/index.ejs#L359)

[Open in Gitpod](http://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/Allanksr/appmeunegocio)

Comment: Hello, people would like to see the process of setting the cookie with an array on it, then getting the value of that cookie and push another value. would you consider specify this?