# Cookie Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I"m trying to create a 2 dimensional array as a cookie in javascript. Is this possible? First of all, how do I create this array cookie? Second of all, how do I loop through this array cookie in order to retrieve data. Thanks alot!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1959455/how-to-store-an-array-in-jquery-cookie

Comment: A little clarification, given that you wonder if it's possible. Cookies are simple plain text dictionary entries composed of key and value: `foo=bar`. You can't even have real *numbers* in cookies. However, you can *emulate* any data type if you are able to represent it as text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You combine the use [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin and [JSON](http://www.json.org/) and solve your problem.

When you want to store an array,You created an array in JS and use `JSON.stringify` to transform it into an string and stored with `$.cookie('name', 'array_string')`

```
var myAry = [1, 2, 3];
$.cookie('name', JSON.stringify(myAry));
```

When you want to retrive the array inside the cookie, you use `$.cookie('name')` to retrive the cookie value and use `JSON.parse` to retrive the array from the string.

```
var storedAry = JSON.parse($.cookie('name'));
//storedAry -> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply!!! That was really helpful. I'm having another issue looping through the string result "var storedAry = JSON.parse($.cookie('name'));". Can you help me out with a snippet?

Comment: Blingue - Consider to mark the answer if you consider it a solution to your problem. This and upvoting answers is what makes the stackoverflow so useful of finding solved problems.

Comment: @Blingue what you need is [Loop through the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @Blingue you'd better check this post(click the left 'tick' icon) as the right answer as for others who has the same questions as yours.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the array as a [JSON](http://json.org/) array in your cookie. From the cookie point of view, its a regular text string but you can parse the content to re-build the array.