# js-cookie: Cookies.get('cookieName') returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, js-cookie

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) for a JQuery plugin I'm coding... I save inside a cookie a specific data created by the user in this way:

```
// Update cookies checks if the cookie esists.
// If cookie exists => push data {myData:[obj1[, obj2, [...], objN]]}
// If cookie doesn't exists => create cookie with {myData:[obj1]}
function _updateCookie(name, cookie, data) {
    // Check if cookie exists
    var cookies = {myData:[]};

    // _getCookie(name) { return Cookies.get(name) }
    if (_getCookie(name) != undefined) {
        cookies = _getCookie(name);
    }

    cookies.reminders.push(cookie);

    Cookies.set(name, cookies, data);
}
```

**DATA:**

```
var data = {
    expires: 1,
    path: '/',
    domain: '',
    secure: true
}
```

**COOKIE:**

```
var cookie = {
    myData: [
        1: myObject1,
        2: myObject2,
        // [...]
        n: myObjectN
    ],
}
```

When I call `_getCookie(name)` it always returns `undefined`. I've also tried to list the cookies with:

```
console.log(Cookies.get());
// log: Object {_ga: "GA1.1.402426237.1450622600"}
```

But if i look at chrome://settings/cookies i see:

*2 cookies on localhost [_ga], [myCookie]*

Any suggestion of what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I saw that the problem comes out when i call `Cookie.set();` with this values

```
Cookies.set('myCookie', {[expires: ...], path: '', domain: ''});
```

if I call

```
Cookies.set('myCookie'{[expires: ...]});
```

I can get the cookie with no problems.

Comment: you had save cookie in Array and accessing only via name. You should access like `myData[0]`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Can you provide how you are pushing your cookie? what data you want to push and access?

Comment: the `_updateCookie()` function checks at first time if the cookie exists, if it doesn't it creates it like: Cookies.set('myCookie', {myData:[array]}, {expires: 1, secure: true, path: '/', domain: ''});

Comment: I'm editing also the question

Comment: try `Cookies.getJSON()` to get cookie. what are you getting from this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98480/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-ilgala).

Comment: You have to do JSON.stringify on your cookie Array before storing. May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163815/cookie-array-in-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @ParthTrivedi please check github... **This project was moved to https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie, check the discussion.

New issues should be opened at https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/issues**
I'm using the new project, the param $.cookie.json and JSON.stringify have been removed...