# use an array which is defined in another file using react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

I have a react component that I use it in some routes.
the component needs some data witch is different in routes. The component is like below:

```
import React from "react";

class ChangeView extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button type="button" className="btn open-modal" title="change view">
                    <i className="fas fa-eye"></i>
                </button>
                <div id="ms">
                    <ul>{data}</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ChangeView;
```

and a sample route:

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import ChangeView from 'ChangeView';
class Firewall extends Component {
  render() {
    const data = [
       {name:"smith",age:20},
       {name:"nik",age:10},
       {name:"mosh",age:45}
    ];
    return(
      <ChangeView />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use cookies for storing object.  Use `localStorage` instead.  Here's how you **[set a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)** and how to **[get a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to store Javascript array as a Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980143/i-want-to-store-javascript-array-as-a-cookie) and [Create array in cookie with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470477)

Answer (score 1):

that not valid way to store the cookies, do it like this

```
document.cookie=  "mycookie=" + json_str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not meant to be used for objects or Arraylists and so on. You should only use strings for cookies, you can however make a serialization of that array to a string and add that to the cookie. But this is really not how it is supposed to be used. Also the browser might drop the cookie due to its length.