# How do I create and read a value from cookie with javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can I create and read a value from a cookie in JavaScript?

Comment: Quirks mode has [a good guide to JavaScript and cookies.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Comment: FWIW, [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) provides a very good API for handling it.

Comment: Don't forget that the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), could be a good alternative to cookies in some situations.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Here are functions you can use for creating and retrieving cookies.

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if your cookie value contains anything that doesn't encode/decode well. The one [at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) seems to work beautifly

Comment: [This simple wrapper from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support) has explicit unicode support mentioned as well

Comment: @BradParks Too bad it's released on GPL.

Comment: This will not work on IE8 or 9 if the cookie does not have a value, because IE does not add the equal sign (**=**) after the cookie name. What we do is to check if **indexOf("=")==-1**, and if so use the entire cookie as the cookie name.

Comment: @jahu And I would say it is also in the public domain: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/About#Copyrights_and_licenses

Comment: @Chronial might be, but it's not 100% clear. The documentation mentioned some older code being available under different licenses (but the block indicating that is no longer in use on the site). Another part mentioned forcing people contributing code to do so under public domain, but that part might have not been there where this particular code was added (I presume the code has been there for a while). In other words MDN has a bit of a mess in therms of licenses of older content, but one might as well pretend they don't and assume that everything is under PD or MIT.

Comment: It fails. Returns a value for any ending substring of the key: `setCookie('test', 'foo'); getCookie('est') -> 'foo'`. It doesn't encode values: `createCookie('test', 'foo; bar'); getCookie('test') -> 'foo'`

Comment: Can anybody clarify why `unescape` is used in the getter, but `escape` is not used in the setter? Is `unescape` really needed? Should `escape` be added?

Comment: FYI, `toGMTString()` is deprecated: [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString)

Answer (score 74):

Minimalistic and full featured ES6 approach:

```
const setCookie = (name, value, days = 7, path = '/') => {
  const expires = new Date(Date.now() + days * 864e5).toUTCString()
  document.cookie = name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '; expires=' + expires + '; path=' + path
}

const getCookie = (name) => {
  return document.cookie.split('; ').reduce((r, v) => {
    const parts = v.split('=')
    return parts[0] === name ? decodeURIComponent(parts[1]) : r
  }, '')
}

const deleteCookie = (name, path) => {
  setCookie(name, '', -1, path)
}
```

Comment: Sometimes cookie value itself may contain `=` sign. In that case function `getCookie` will produce unexpected result. To avoid that consider using following arrow function body inside reduce
`const [n, ...val] = v.split('=');  
return n === name ? decodeURIComponent(val.join('=')) : r`

Comment: Would be nice to have an option to leave the expiry date unset though. This would allow the cookie to be automatically deleted upon browser exit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706852/87520 allows for all characters, and allows all options and their defaults.

Comment: `864e5 = 86400000 = 1000*60*60*24` represents the number of milliseconds in a 24 hour day.

Comment: Pls, be aware that the above `getCooki` with `reduce` **won't work properly for multiple cookies** with the same name (possible for different paths, e.g. `/` and `/faq`). Chrome always provides cookies for the current path at the beginning of the `document.cookie` string. This reducer overwrites `r` value and returns the last found cookie value (so the value for `/` path instead of the current path value).

Reduce also has poor performance (less important in this case), I made benchmarks here: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/16012/2/getcookie-forof-vs-indexof-vs-find-vs-reduce

Comment: Here is a **fixed version** of this function with `=` in value & duplicated name support: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70118256/8573721 - but since it has poor performance I would consider other alternatives from that answer (there are comparisons).

Answer (score 44):

[JQuery Cookies](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/)

or plain Javascript:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
   var exdate=new Date();
   exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
   var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ("; expires="+exdate.toUTCString()));
   document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
   var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
   for (i=0; i<ARRcookies.length; i++)
   {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name)
      {
        return unescape(y);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm marking this up primarily because you mentioned JQuery Cookies. I would recommend that. The code is very small and if you're using JQuery already, it is just the correct thing to use.

Answer (score 24):

ES7, using a regex for get(). Based on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie)

```
const Cookie = {
    get: name => {
        let c = document.cookie.match(`(?:(?:^|.*; *)${name} *= *([^;]*).*$)|^.*$`)[1]
        if (c) return decodeURIComponent(c)
    },
    set: (name, value, opts = {}) => {
        /*If options contains days then we're configuring max-age*/
        if (opts.days) {
            opts['max-age'] = opts.days * 60 * 60 * 24;

            /*Deleting days from options to pass remaining opts to cookie settings*/
            delete opts.days 
        }

        /*Configuring options to cookie standard by reducing each property*/
        opts = Object.entries(opts).reduce(
            (accumulatedStr, [k, v]) => `${accumulatedStr}; ${k}=${v}`, ''
        )

        /*Finally, creating the key*/
        document.cookie = name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + opts
    },
    delete: (name, opts) => Cookie.set(name, '', {'max-age': -1, ...opts}) 
    // path & domain must match cookie being deleted 
}
```

---

```
Cookie.set('user', 'Jim', {path: '/', days: 10}) 
// Set the path to top level (instead of page) and expiration to 10 days (instead of session)
```

Usage - Cookie.get(name, value [, options]):
options supports all standard cookie options and adds "days":

- **path**: '/' - any absolute path. *Default*: current document location,
- **domain**: 'sub.example.com' - may not start with dot. *Default*: current host without subdomain.
- **secure**: true - Only serve cookie over https. *Default*: false.
- **days**: 2 - days till cookie expires. *Default*: End of session.
  Alternative ways of setting expiration:

  - **expires**: 'Sun, 18 Feb 2018 16:23:42 GMT' - date of expiry as a GMT string.
    Current date can be gotten with: new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString()
  - **'max-age'**: 30 - same as days, but in seconds instead of days.

Other answers use "expires" instead of "max-age" to support older IE versions. This method requires ES7, so IE7 is out anyways (this is not a big deal).

Note: Funny characters such as "=" and "{:}" are supported as cookie values, and the regex handles leading and trailing whitespace (from other libs).
If you would like to store objects, either encode them before and after with and JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, edit the above, or add another method. Eg:

```
Cookie.getJSON = name => JSON.parse(Cookie.get(name))
Cookie.setJSON = (name, value, opts) => Cookie.set(name, JSON.stringify(value), opts);
```

Comment: Would the downvoters kindly explain what's wrong with my method?

Comment: 1. Shorter, and IMO easier to maintain. 2. More complete (is the only answer to accept secure, any order of arguments, max-age). 3. More standard defaults (path etc defaults to the standard, unlike most answers here). 4. Best practice (according to MDN, the regex is the most reliable way to extract the values). 5. Futureprook (if more options are added to cookies, they will be maintained). 6. One object pollutes the code less than a bunch of functions. 7. Get, set and delete and easy to add more methods. 8. ES7 (yummy buzzwords).

Comment: 1) vscode is telling me I have to specify ES9 support for use of this line-
"delete: (name, opts) => Cookie.set(name, '', {'max-age': -1, ...opts})". 
Is that what you found too?  2) to do a Cookie.get, can I just specify (name) versus (name, value). I may not know the value and am using the get to retrieve it.

Comment: @Ric. 1. I don't get an error in VSCode. This has been valid since ES7, so not sure why you should have an issue. 2. When you are trying to retrieve the value, you don't know it yet. Do Cookie.get('name') w/o the value, and it will will return the value if it has been set. Hope that helps :)

Comment: I'm completely with you, I thought it was ES7 too. Here is a link to the graphic of the error msg. Thx for help on point #2.
https://i.imgur.com/uWNLXXE.png

Comment: I've been implementing your cookie code above and have found a weird experience. If I only code  the opts attribute "domain:", the last line "document.cookie = ..." works as expected, and writes a cookie. But for some reason when I add any other option the last same line appears to execute without bombing but the variable document.cookie always equals "".  Any ideas here?

Comment: There's no need to minify variables on Stack Overflow like `c` `k` `v`, `str`, `opts`, just use real variable names.

Comment: @mikemaccana: When you solve math on a napkin, do you use `number + 5 = 15` or `integer * 7 = 14`? `i` and `int` are perfectly well known and accepted variable names, as are `n` and `num`. {`key`: `val`} and {`k`: `v`} are as clear as {`key`: `value`}. `str`, `arr`, `obj`, are as verbose as they need to be, and `opts` is no less clear than then options. You can use an `&` instead of the word `and` even in a language that permits both. **Verbosity is a virtue only when it adds clarity.**

Comment: @SamGoody In code (which isn’t mathematics), most people would do age + yearBorn = currentYear. Unlike mathematics, code sticks around and is read more than it is written and the overhead of having to find out that ‘c’ is cookie is unnecessary on those reading your code. This is why single character variable names are not considered good practice. You’re welcome to argue about this but I don’t think Stack Overflow is the place to do this.

Comment: +9000.  This is an excellent answer.  I added one more item to my `Cookie` definition: `MAX_AGE_SECONDS: 2147483647,`  This I use with `set(..., ..., {"max-age": Cookie.MAX_AGE_SECONDS})`  That crazy number comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22479460/257299

Comment: It might also be nice to add (optional?) check in `set()` to throw exception if final cookie text exceeds 4,000 chars.  Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key

Comment: this code is mumbo jumbo unreadable, but maybe it was good by 2018 standards

Answer (score 19):

Mozilla created a [simple framework for reading and writing cookies with full unicode support](https://gist.github.com/jasdeepkhalsa/4654184) along with examples of how to use it.

Once included on the page, you can set a cookie:

```
docCookies.setItem(name, value);
```

read a cookie:

```
docCookies.getItem(name);
```

or delete a cookie:

```
docCookies.removeItem(name);
```

For example:

```
// sets a cookie called 'myCookie' with value 'Chocolate Chip'
docCookies.setItem('myCookie', 'Chocolate Chip');

// reads the value of a cookie called 'myCookie' and assigns to variable
var myCookie = docCookies.getItem('myCookie');

// removes the cookie called 'myCookie'
docCookies.removeItem('myCookie');
```

See more examples and details on [Mozilla's document.cookie page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support).

A version of this simple js file is [on github](https://github.com/madmurphy/cookies.js/blob/master/cookies.js).

Comment: Please note that the cookie library provided on MDN is released under the GPL, not LGPL.

Comment: What javascript file do I need to import? Couldn't find it :(

Comment: See the section under "Library" on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support - you can save it to a file and include it or paste it into an existing js file where you'd like to use it.

Comment: So no standalone javascript file? So it's a code snippet - not an actual library.

Comment: Great input! The "library" is a single .js file with ~80 lines; it's this file (on GitHub): https://github.com/madmurphy/cookies.js/blob/master/cookies.js

Comment: Top link is dead.

Answer (score 11):

For those who need save objects like {foo: 'bar'}, I share my edited version of @KevinBurke's answer. I've added JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, that's all.

```
cookie = {

    set: function (name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else
            var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + JSON.stringify(value) + expires + "; path=/";
    },

    get : function(name){
        var nameEQ = name + "=",
            ca = document.cookie.split(';');

        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) 
              return  JSON.parse(c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length));
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

So, now you can do things like this:

```
cookie.set('cookie_key', {foo: 'bar'}, 30);

cookie.get('cookie_key'); // {foo: 'bar'}

cookie.set('cookie_key', 'baz', 30);

cookie.get('cookie_key'); // 'baz'
```

Answer (score 9):

I've used accepted answer of this thread many times already. It's great piece of code: Simple and usable. But I usually use [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/) and ES6 and modules, so if you are like me, here is code to copy for faster developing with ES6

[Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4825695/1737158) rewritten as module with ES6:

```
export const createCookie = ({name, value, days}) => {
  let expires;
  if (days) {
    let date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString();
  } else {
    expires = '';
  }
  document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
};

export const getCookie = ({name}) => {
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    let c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + '=');
    if (c_start !== -1) {
      c_start = c_start + name.length + 1;
      let c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(';', c_start);
      if (c_end === -1) {
        c_end = document.cookie.length;
      }
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
  }
  return '';
};
```

And after this you can simply import it as any module (path of course may vary):

```
import {createCookie, getCookie} from './../helpers/Cookie';
```

Comment: FYI: `toGMTString()` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString#browser_compatibility. Use `toUTCString()` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a code to [Get, Set and Delete Cookie in JavaScript](http://mycodingtricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-cookies/).

```js
function getCookie(name) {
    name = name + "=";
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        while (cookie.charAt(0)==' ') {
            cookie = cookie.substring(1);
        }
        if (cookie.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return cookie.substring(name.length,cookie.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function setCookie(name, value, expirydays) {
 var d = new Date();
 d.setTime(d.getTime() + (expirydays*24*60*60*1000));
 var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
 document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; " + expires;
}

function deleteCookie(name){
  setCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Source: http://mycodingtricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-cookies/

Comment: Both links dead

Answer (score 6):

### Performance benchmark

Comparison of **ES6 versions** of some popular `getCookie` functions (with my improvements):
https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/16012/5/getcookie-for-vs-forof-vs-indexof-vs-find-vs-reduce

**TL;DR**: `for...of` version seams to be fastest for real-life cookies data :)

> **Important:** `document.cookie` can provide **duplicated cookie names** if there are cookies with the same name for `path=/` and current page path (eg. `path=/faq`). But the cookie for the current path will always be the first in the string, so be aware of this when using the `reduce()` version from the other answer provided here (it returns the last found cookie instead of the first one).
>
> Fixed `reduce()` version is further in my answer.

### For..of version:

Fastest for the real-life benchmark data set (10 cookies with long values). But performance results are almost the same as with vanilla `for` loop and with `Array.find()`, so use which you like :)

```js
function getCookieForOf(name) {
  const nameEQ = name + '=';
  for (const cookie of document.cookie.split('; ')) {
    if (cookie.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
      const value = cookie.substring(nameEQ.length);
      return decodeURIComponent(value); // returns first found cookie
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

### IndexOf version

**Incredibly fast** in the artificial test set of 1000 cookies with short values (because it doesn't create an array with 1000 records). To be honest, I consider there could be a bug in the test code that makes this version so crazy fast (if you would find some, pls let me know). Anyway, it's rather not probable to have 1000 cookies in the real App ;)

It's slow for the real-world test data set with 10 long cookies.

```js
function getCookieIndexOf(name) {
  const nameEQ = name + '=';
  const cookies = document.cookie;
  const cookieStart = cookies.indexOf(nameEQ);
  if (cookieStart !== -1) {
    const cookieValueStart = cookieStart + nameEQ.length;
    const cookieEnd = cookies.indexOf(';', cookieValueStart);
    const value = cookies.substring(
      cookieValueStart,
      cookieEnd !== -1 ? cookieEnd : undefined
    );
    return decodeURIComponent(value); // returns first found cookie
  }
  return null;
}
```

### Array.find() version

```js
function getCookieFind(name) {
  const nameEQ = name + '=';
  const foundCookie = document.cookie
    .split('; ')
    .find(c => c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0); // returns first found cookie
  if (foundCookie) {
    return decodeURIComponent(foundCookie.substring(nameEQ.length));
  }
  return null;
}
```

### Vanilla, old-school, for-loop version ;)

```js
function getCookieFor(name) {
    const nameEQ = name + "=";
    const ca = cookies.split('; ');
    for(let i=0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        const c = ca[i];
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
          const value = c.substring(nameEQ.length);
          return decodeURIComponent(value); // returns first found cookie
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// ES5 version:
function getCookieFor(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = cookies.split('; ');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
          var value = c.substring(nameEQ.length);
          return decodeURIComponent(value); // returns first found cookie
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

### Array.reduce() version

My fixed version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38699214/8573721) from @artnikpro - returns the first found cookie, so works better with duplicated cookie names for the current path (e.g. `path=/faq`) and `path=/`.

This version is the slowest one in all performance tests, so IMHO should be avoided.

```js
function getCookieReduce(name) {
  return document.cookie.split('; ').reduce((r, v) => {
    const [n, ...val] = v.split('='); // cookie value can contain "="
    if(r) return r; // returns first found cookie
    return n === name ? decodeURIComponent(val.join('=')) : r; // returns last found cookie (overwrites)
  }, '');
}
```

You can **run benchmarks** by yourself here: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/16012/5/getcookie-for-vs-forof-vs-indexof-vs-find-vs-reduce

---

## setCookie() TypeScript function

Here is also my version of the function to set a cookie with `encodeURIComponent`, `TypeScript`, and `SameSite` option (which will be [required by Firefox soon](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/08/changes-to-samesite-cookie-behavior/)):

```ts
function setCookie(
  name: string,
  value: string = '',
  days: number | false = false, // session length if not provided
  path: string = '/', // provide an empty string '' to set for current path (managed by a browser)
  sameSite: 'none' | 'lax' | 'strict' = 'lax', // required by Firefox
  isSecure?: boolean
) {
  let expires = '';
  if (days) {
    const date = new Date(
      Date.now() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ).toUTCString();
    expires = '; expires=' + date;
  }
  const secure = isSecure || sameSite === 'none' ? `; Secure` : '';
  const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(value);
  document.cookie = `${name}=${encodedValue}${expires}; path=${path}; SameSite=${sameSite}${secure}`;
}
```

## Google Chrome Cookie Storage API

Thanks to @oncode [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65309828/8573721) it's worth mentioning that the Google Chrome team has proposed some standardization (finally! It's really ridiculous that we still don't have any commonly accepted API for cookies) with asynchronous Cookie Storage API (available in Google Chrome starting from version 87): https://wicg.github.io/cookie-store/

Unfortunately, it's still unofficial and isn't even under W3C consideration nor ES proposal: github.com/tc39/proposals

Such a shame we still don't have any standard API for cookies...

Fortunately, we have `cookie-store` polyfill for other browsers as [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-store) ([gitHub](https://github.com/mkay581/cookie-store)), which is only [1.7kB Gzipped](https://bundlephobia.com/package/cookie-store@3.0.0) ;)

Answer (score 2):

I use this object. Values are encoded, so it's necessary to consider it when reading or writing from server side.

```
cookie = (function() {

/**
 * Sets a cookie value. seconds parameter is optional
 */
var set = function(name, value, seconds) {
    var expires = seconds ? '; expires=' + new Date(new Date().getTime() + seconds * 1000).toGMTString() : '';
    document.cookie = name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + '; path=/';
};

var map = function() {
    var map = {};
    var kvs = document.cookie.split('; ');
    for (var i = 0; i < kvs.length; i++) {
        var kv = kvs[i].split('=');
        map[kv[0]] = decodeURIComponent(kv[1]);
    }
    return map;
};

var get = function(name) {
    return map()[name];
};

var remove = function(name) {
    set(name, '', -1);
};

return {
    set: set,
    get: get,
    remove: remove,
    map: map
};

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to success.

```
<script src="/path/to/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
  Cookies.set('foo', 'bar');
  Cookies.get('foo');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use my [cookie ES module](https://github.com/anhr/commonNodeJS/tree/master/cookieNodeJS) for get/set/remove cookie.

### Usage:

In your head tag, include the following code:

```
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/anhr/commonNodeJS/master/cookieNodeJS/build/cookie.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/anhr/commonNodeJS/master/cookieNodeJS/build/cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Now you can use window.cookie for store user information in web pages.

#### cookie.isEnabled()

Is the cookie enabled in your web browser?

```
returns {boolean} true if cookie enabled.
```

Example

```
if ( cookie.isEnabled() )
    console.log('cookie is enabled on your browser');
else
    console.error('cookie is disabled on your browser');
```

#### cookie.set( name, value )

Set a cookie.

```
name: cookie name.
value: cookie value.
```

Example

```
cookie.set('age', 25);
```

#### cookie.get( name[, defaultValue] );

get a cookie.

```
name: cookie name.
defaultValue: cookie default value. Default is undefined.
returns cookie value or defaultValue if cookie was not found
```

##### Example

```
var age = cookie.get('age', 25);
```

#### cookie.remove( name );

Remove cookie.

```
name: cookie name.
```

##### Example

```
cookie.remove( 'age' );
```

[Example of usage](https://raw.githack.com/anhr/commonNodeJS/master/cookieNodeJS/Examples/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

The chrome team has proposed a new way of managing cookies asynchronous with the Cookie Storage API (available in Google Chrome starting from version 87): https://wicg.github.io/cookie-store/

Use it already today with a polyfill for the other browsers: https://github.com/mkay581/cookie-store

```js
// load polyfill
import 'cookie-store';

// set a cookie
await cookieStore.set('name', 'value');
// get a cookie
const savedValue = await cookieStore.get('name');
```

Comment: Thx a lot for sharing this! Unfortunately, it's still unofficial and isn't even under W3C consideration nor ES proposal: https://github.com/tc39/proposals

Such a shame we still don't have any standard API for cookies... it's ridiculous :P
Fortunately `cookie-store` is only 1.7kB Gzipped ;) https://bundlephobia.com/package/cookie-store@3.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Very short ES6 functions using template literals. Be aware that you need to encode/decode the values by yourself but it'll work out of the box for simplier purposes like storing version numbers.

```
const getCookie = (cookieName) => {
  return (document.cookie.match(`(^|;) *${cookieName}=([^;]*)`)||[])[2]
}
  
const setCookie = (cookieName, value, days=360, path='/') => {
  let expires = (new Date(Date.now()+ days*86400*1000)).toUTCString();
  document.cookie = `${cookieName}=${value};expires=${expires};path=${path};`
}

const deleteCookie = (cookieName) => {
  document.cookie = `${cookieName}=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;path=/;`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following functions, which I have written by taking the best I have found from various sources and weeded out some bugs or discrepancies.

The function setCookie does not have advanced options, just the simple stuff, but the code is easy to understand, which is always a plus:

```
function setCookie(name, value, daysToLive = 3650) { // 10 years default
  let cookie = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
  if (typeof daysToLive === "number") {
    cookie += "; max-age=" + (daysToLive * 24 * 60 * 60);
    document.cookie = cookie + ";path=/";
  }
}
function getCookie(name) {
  let cookieArr = document.cookie.split(";");
  for (let i = 0; i < cookieArr.length; i++) {
    let cookiePair = cookieArr[i].split("=");
    if (name == cookiePair[0].trim()) {
      return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1].trim());
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
function deleteCookie(name) {
  setCookie(name, '', -1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For reading simple querystrings, this one-liner might work for you in recent versions of JavaScript:

```
let cookies = Object.fromEntries(document.cookie.split(';').map(i=>i.trim().split('=')));
```

And now you have a JavaScript Object with keys and values.

For creating, you can try this one:

```
let cookieObject = {foo: 'bar', ping: "pong"}
Object.entries(cookieObject).map((e)=>`${e[0]}=${e[1]}`).join(';')
```

Comment: What do you recommend for writing cookies?

Comment: @Crashalot i added one for writing, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to read cookies in ES6.

```
function getCookies() {
    var cookies = {};
    for (let cookie of document.cookie.split('; ')) {
        let [name, value] = cookie.split("=");
        cookies[name] = decodeURIComponent(value);
    }
    console.dir(cookies);
}
```

Comment: cookies can contain '=' in a value string. This code won't work.

Comment: The question is also about creating cookies, not just reading them

Answer (score 0):

Through a interface similar to `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`:

```
const cookieStorage = {
  getItem: (key) {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';')
      .map(cookie => cookie.split('='))
      .reduce(
        (accumulation, [key, value]) => ({...accumulation, [key.trim()]: value}),
        {}
      )
    
    return cookies[key]
  },
  setItem: (key, value) {
    document.cookie = `${key}=${value}`
  },
}
```

Its usage `cookieStorage.setItem('', '')` and `cookieStorage.getItem('')`.

Answer (score -1):

I have written simple cookieUtils, it has three functions for creating the cookie, reading the cookie and deleting the cookie.

```
var CookieUtils = {
    createCookie: function (name, value, expireTime) {
        expireTime = !!expireTime ? expireTime : (15 * 60 * 1000); // Default 15 min
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + expireTime);
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    },
    getCookie: function (name) {
        var value = "; " + document.cookie;
        var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
        }
    },
    deleteCookie: function(name) {
        document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the example from [w3chools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) that was mentioned.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple read

```
var getCookie = function (name) {
    var valueStart = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=") + name.length + 1;
    var valueEnd = document.cookie.indexOf(";", valueStart); 
    return document.cookie.slice(valueStart, valueEnd)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A cheeky and simple way of reading a cookie could be something like:

```
let username, id; 
eval(document.cookie); 
console.log(username + ", " + id); // John Doe, 123
```

This could be used if you know your cookie contains something like: `username="John Doe"; id=123;`. Note that a string would need quotes in the cookie. Not the recommended way probably, but works for testing/learning.