# Set cookie with array() in jquery

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to check if a cookie (id) is set or not: if not set, then create it. If set, retrieve the value (= an array). How can I retrieve the array from the cookie? 
I hear that I would have to use JSON, but I'm not sure how that would work with the following code?

```
function start(id){
 if (document.cookie.indexOf('id') === -1 ) {
     setCookie('id', id, 7);
    } 
 else {
    var playedID = [GET COOKIE ARRAY]
    playedID.push(id); 
    setCookie('id',playedID);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Frankly, I didn't find out what you want to do exactly and what is your problem!

Comment: Not getting what this code `push.playedID(id);` does? Could you please explain.

Comment: ok so playedID should be an array (the array of IDs saved in the cookie)
and push. is a mistake, I corrected it, it should be playedID.push() in order to add a new id to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it based on some helper functions to make sure you are parsing and stringifying the cookie correctly.

getCookie and setCookie are from https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```js
// This won't run due to security policies on this site, but you can run it in the dev tools and see.

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookieArray(cname) {
  var cookie = getCookie(cname);
  return cookie ? JSON.parse(cookie) : [];
}

function pushToCookieArray(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var cookieArray = getCookieArray(cname);
  cookieArray.push(cvalue);
  setCookie(cname, JSON.stringify(cookieArray), exdays);
}

function start(id) {
  pushToCookieArray('id', id, 7);
  console.log(getCookieArray('id'));
}

start(5);
start(6);
start(8);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First a cookie is not stored as an array but a string : if you type `document.cookie` in you console, you will get all the cookies from the website you are visiting, separated with a coma.

So as explained here : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp, 
 you will have to create a custom function to access the cookie you need.

2. Then the value of you cookie is still a string, so as explained here if you want to save an array of ids, you have to use `JSON.stringify` to encode you array as a string : [I want to store Javascript array as a Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980143/i-want-to-store-javascript-array-as-a-cookie/2980163)

You can then create it or update its value :

```js
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";";
}

function start(id){
 if (getCookie('id') === '' ) {
     setCookie('id', JSON.stringify([+id]));
    }
 else {
    let ids = JSON.parse(getCookie('id'))
    console.log(ids)
    ids.push(+id); 
    setCookie('id', JSON.stringify(ids));
  } 
}

function sendID(id) {
  console.log(document.getElementById("user-id").value)
  start(id);
  alert(getCookie("id"))
}
```

Here is a working example : https://codepen.io/adrientiburce/pen/ExVbYWy?editors=1010